# Convergent or divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series: 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}}$

I must investigate if it is divergent or convergent. I have tried different approaches like the root test, but it didn't help me:(. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Best regards, Petar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For large $n$, the $n$th term of your series is roughly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Can you think of another series whose convergence/divergence behavior is known and whose terms can be compared with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$? Try using the [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test) between your original series and the new series.

Comment: Ah, got it! We know that the harmonic series is divergent. Its members are less than `1/sqrt(n)`. So if `1/sqrt(n)` was convergent also the harmonic series would be convergent. This is a contradiction, so our series is divergent. Thank you again!

Comment: @Petar: You are right. In dealing with convergence questions, it is always useful to try to get a rough idea of what the $n$ term looks like. In cases when you can get a simple approximation for the $n$th term, comparison test is handy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is what I was missing.